# Why is my h1 all cramped?

Tags: css, fonts, typography

On [my website](http://www.40quidblogs.co.uk) I have an `<H1>` (the first one) with a title in it but it is all cramped. I've checked the CSS and can't see why it is all squeezed together. Can you help me find the culprit?

Comment: I would suggest in the future for such simple CSS questions, download Chrome (or firebug for Firefox) and right click on the element in question and select **inspect element**. The inspectors show you a breakdown of all CSS rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because of this:

**style.css(line 115)**

```
body{
  12px/1.5em sans-serif <===
  ...
}
```

Comment: Wow removing this worked but now it is spaced too far apart between each new line. Just used firebug to check if any line-height is inherited and i don't see any. Further input on reducing thye gapos between new lines of header highly appreciated.

Comment: @MarkR, you simply have you define a `line-height:` for your `<h1>` then.  you set a font-size of 12px in your body, but a line height of `em` I would suggest NOT mixing em vs px etc; stay consistent.

Comment: This is a theme by woo themes, I thought they should know better. Even I can code quicker than this but I use themes to speed up the process. Just awful to have to use their silly css and whatnot. May I ask where you see the line-height and 12px being inherited from.. when I use firebug it doesn't say where these are being inherited from. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkR, I was referring to your `body` that I've identified, just add the font-height to your h1 and define it, it will not inherit from anywhere else once you define line-height for h1.

Comment: Thank you very much. You've helped me understand line-height. Never before have I had to use it except in navigation links. Thanks and best wishes. Mark

Answer (score 1):

You set `line-height` on the body, and you're surprised that the line height is messed up? Remove that style and you're all fixed.

Comment: I removed that and it's still messed up. Confused with it now. Even using Firebug i can't figure it out.

Comment: Considering I just removed that CSS rule with Developer Tools and everything magically fell into place, I'm pretty sure I'm right here...

Answer (score 0):

set your line-height to 1 (default). `line-height: 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this line:

```
.entry h1, .entry h2, .entry h3, .entry h4, .entry h5, .entry h6 { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0 0 0.5em; line-height:1.5em; }
```

Which is in swatch/styles.css.

That line-height property is probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `line-height` for your headings. By looking at the font, try a `line-height: 1.1em`. i.e.

`h1{
  line-height: 1.1em;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your line-height in your css. For example

```
h1
{
   line-height: 30px;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Whats messing your H1 is the `font: 12px/1.5em sans-serif;` in your body style in you style.css line 115.

Answer (score 0):

The element enclosing the `h1` element has its width set to 50%. This forces the long heading across several lines. Remove that setting and shorten the heading.

Answer (score 0):

Another same answer, but necessary:

Somehow unset line-heights for h1..6 are inherited from parent elements if parent elements have set line-heights. Tested in Firefox 24, Chrome 30 and ie8.

So here is another line for the reset area of css, to reset h1..6 line-heights and to prevent inherit behaviour:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
line-height:normal; /*otherwise line-height is inherited*/
}
```